# WebPlayer throwing error when one of the IL added in spotfire

Tags: spotfire, spotfire-webplayer

I have total of 12 IL in a report which are added as rows to each other. But due to the one IL:" DD_D30-C6" , the web player URL is not working. Even though its working fine in Spotfire Editor but not in the web player URL.
There is no such logs or error msg recorded, I compared this IL to other IL , syntax wise everything is proper only.Error msg is as attached.

[image: Web Player Error]

Comment: Does the information link contain parameters? I believe that if there are parameters defined in the IL, they need to have values passed from document properties (the web player will not display the pop-up input field).

Comment: Hi Fisto,
Yes i have mentionedall the parameters in Config block and its works fine, but as soon i add one specific IL and save it then it wont work in web player(whereas it work fine in spotfire editor)

https://us-spotfire.solutions.iqvia.com/spotfire/wp/OpenAnalysis?file=/Team%20Folders/QECG/SMS%20Spotfire%20Reports/Dev%20Integration/FinanceReportECG&configurationBlock=Maxdate%20%3D%20%7B%2210-Mar-2018%2000%3A00%3A00%22%7D;Mindate%20%3D%20%7B%2210-Feb-2018%2000%3A00%3A00%22%7D;

Answer (score 0):

Figured out the answer:
 Out of all the 12 IL i have added as rows to by reports, this one particular IL (DD_D36-C6) has a datatype mismatch . ALl IL were having "Datetime" as datatype while this one has "string" datatype associated with it. Hence while running it in webplayer it was not successful.